# Document.AI python client does not return tables

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I want to use Document.ai to extract data from tables in my pdf.

I was following this code snippet https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#code_samples_2

But my table array is always empty. I tried to do it with pdf provided by google or with mine. But it doesn't work.

When I put this documents into drag'n'drop example it work flawlessly https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/drag-and-drop

Is there some trick to make it work with python client?

Comment: Did you change something from the code snippet?

Comment: No, I haven't. I just added `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you're sending the document to a [Form Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser) processor, as that's the processor type that can extract tables.

If you're already using the form parser, it would be helpful to provide the document you're using and the sample output from Document AI.

**Update:** The Demo has been updated to show that Tables are extracted using the Form Parser.

---

[image]

---

[image]